# Does iteration go through the whole list

Tags: c++, iteration, stdlist

Take this code:

```
std::list<int> intList;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    intList.push_back( 1 << i );
}

std::list<int>::const_iterator iterator;
for (iterator = intList.begin(); iterator != intList.end(); ++iterator) {
    std::cout << *iterator;
}
```

I see how to iterate through a list. Looking at the iteration I think you skip the last item. Is this the case and if so what is the best way to solve it.

Comment: You should provide appropriate code snippets here, not links.

Comment: The link shows three ways of iterating through the list. Which one are you interested in?

Comment: The image in [this `end` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/end) should hopefully explain things.

Comment: intList.end() does not point to the last element it points to an element after the last one.

Comment: It should also have been explained by [any good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: "Is this the case?" No, it is not the case. You don't need to "solve" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the last item is not skipped. The iterator pointing to `intList.end()-1` points to the last item instead of `intList.end()` as you may be thinking.

Comment: In other words, in any std container, end() points to one past the last element.